# Get FTS index names without information schema

Tags: php, mysql, sql, information-schema

I don't have permission to access information_schema. Can I get a list of FTS indexes for my DB? The following query works but fails for me due to insufficient permission.

```
SELECT i.name as index_name
FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tables t
JOIN information_schema.innodb_sys_indexes i USING (table_id)
WHERE t.name = 'my_db/table_name'
AND i.name like 'fts_%'
```

Is there any alternate way to get the same result?

Note that I have full privilege on `my_db` database only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve it using:

```
SHOW INDEX
  FROM table_name
  WHERE Key_name like 'fts_%'
```

Please post another answer if a better possible solution is available.